# How do I make text grow then shrink while still keeping the same midpoint?

Tags: processing

I'm making a bit of a late father's day present. I need some sort of ____Mode(CENTER) for text. I am trying to make a piece of text expand, then shrink, then expand again, then shrink again, on a loop. However, what I attempt seems to grow and shrink sparatically, making the text move around, and not staying centered. Is there an easy way to do this with text?
Code:

```
String msg = "Happy Father's Day";
int ts = 50;
float textX = 165;
float textY = 312.5;
float tSize = 50;
boolean flip;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  fill(255);
  textSize(tSize);
  text(msg, textX, textY);

  if (flip == false) {
    tSize += 0.5;
    textX -= 1;
    textY -= 1;
  } else if (flip == true) {
    tSize -= 0.5;
    textX += 1;
    textY += 1;
  }
  if (tSize == 35) flip = false;
  else if (tSize == 65) flip = true;
}
```

Comment: oops delete bottom bracket

Comment: Just edit the code (which I did for you) rather than describe the edit in a comment. The code as written has a nice effect, I actually prefer it to the perfectly centered version of the code that I gave in my answer below. I suspect your father would like either version.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than constantly modifying `textX` and `textY`, you can use [textAlign](https://processing.org/reference/textAlign_.html) if you want to keep the text centered. In this case, you can simply drop those 2 variables:

```
String msg = "Happy Father's Day";
int ts = 50;
float tSize = 50;
boolean flip;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  fill(255);
  textSize(tSize);
  text(msg, width/2, height/2);

  if (!flip) {
    tSize += 0.5;
  } else {
    tSize -= 0.5;
  }
  if (tSize == 35) flip = false;
  if (tSize == 65) flip = true;
 }
```

You can streamline your code by making `flip` a number which is always 1 or -1 rather than a Boolean. This reduces the amount of conditional logic required. Note also how the following code replaced the equality comparisons (`==`) with inequalities (`<=` and `>=`). Something like `tSize == 65` does work with steps of size `0.5` (since `0.5` has a finite base-2 expansion) but if you changed `0.5` to e.g. `0.1` to try to make it slower, the value `65` would be skipped over entirely due to floating-point round-off error. Since `tSize` is declared to be a float, using `==` with it is asking for trouble.

```
String msg = "Happy Father's Day";
int ts = 50;
float tSize = 50;
float flip = -1;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  textSize(tSize);
  text(msg, width/2, height/2);
  tSize += flip * 0.5;
  if (tSize <= 35 || tSize >= 65 ) flip *= -1;
 }
```